# TS, implicit inference based on the return type of the first element of a tuplue

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, type-inference

I need to validate a ts inference like this one

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;

  color: string;

  age: number;
}
type Validator<T> = (data: T) => boolean;

const validateString: Validator<string> = (data) => !!data?.length;
const validateNumber: Validator<number> = (data) => data > 0;

// this type should have ts inference
type ValidatorTuple<T> = [(data: T) => unknown, Validator<unknown>];

const validate = <T>(item: T, validator: ValidatorTuple<T>[]) => {
  for (const [predicate, validation] of validator) {
    const value = predicate(item);

    const result = validation(value);

    if (!result) return false;
  }

  return true;
};

//expected result

const dog: Animal = {
  age: 12,
  color: "white",
  name: "josh",
};

const isValid = validate(dog, [
  [(d) => d.age, validateNumber],
  [(d) => d.color, validateString],
  [(d) => d.name, validateNumber], // this should throw a TS error
]);
```

I've tried many ts inference but nothing works

Comment: I see a problem with typing of `const value = predicate(item);` within the loop. In your example, the first time it should be a number, but the second time it should be a string. And if someone manages to turn it into `string | number`, then validation(...) doesn't work.

Comment: I managed to make TS err where you wanted it, but only when I know beforehand that the return types are only `string` and `number`, and had difficulties with the inferred `string | number` type for `const value`, and had to use `//@ts-ignore` to suppress the error in `const result = validation(value);`. (I think it's not really an answer, though, so I didn't post it here).

Comment: @qrsngky no, maybe I explained wrong, I wish that for each element of the validation array, there was a type

[(data: T) => TResult // inferred, Validator <TResult>]
so that in case a user returns a type es Enum, the only acceptable value as a second element is Validator <Enum>

Comment: I know that your main concern is on the bottom part (return type of first function should match the input for the second function in the tuple). What I am saying is that, even if someone manages to fix that, your for loop will have typing problems.

Comment: @qrsngky Are you sure about that? https://tsplay.dev/NdrpXW - I know it's cheating a little with `any`, but it was necessary to make the inference work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that your `unknown`'s were causing the compiler some trouble (see @geoffrey's comment). Changing them to `any` allowed me to do this (it's OK since it won't "bleed" into the rest of the code):

```
const validate = <T, V extends [(data: T) => any, Validator<any>][]>(item: T, validator: [...{
  [K in keyof V]: V[K] extends [(data: T) => infer U, Validator<infer X>]
    ? [U] extends [X]
      ? V[K]
      : [TypeError, "Validator type does not match with value provider."]
    : V[K];
}]) => {
```

Essentially, we're allowing the compiler to infer the type of `V` first, then "looping" over `V` and checking if the validator and "value provider" match. If it doesn't, we "replace" that element with a type error instead.

And as an unintended effect, the body of the function is unaffected. Mainly because the values are now `any` - but that is OK (and technically correct).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAICCEwFskA26A3qOuhErjAFzoDOUckA5gNyhnooD2BPcOo2YR2nEOSQtaFAK64ARvA4gAvqCgBPAA4YAaoTAATJFAEAeACoA+dAF50AChNQkdSwEp7thTz4wkCBVQXghGdAA3QxcYAGUmVjoDAmNTC2FWWwdnUyQvO1sAQkKXJAB+ADoCGFEoAAsVUPColJiAOXklQXRk1LM4cwhO+CynUvzbUvRbAAZgkC1dHui0uEtZbWqrUYBtHNd3CfRZCABrCB4AdwgAGmXW1fMT86uIawBdeaaoSJXYe3QVjuenQMAAHrAIEZ6Og9qVDt50IFNMC-hZkR8du9rI4wLBcO47i0+gI6DsKhTSBJYQBpdCQdCnGCaHgIHrvJI7GnvUEQmrQ2H7NzoTyIyAIeDoACqqIe-XM4slAA0PlxyGVYVKeeDIQKdkr3mryOgNXouYbqcb0GTLDoYABROBwAR3ABEvRcAnQiwwRh4MBhFx++CgKDq6EuePDLVkGG0zoixngFVdFqtnO5KlU7yOVPICC9jm+sPjMCMYBQphgRL+YB4EB5rN+coEXjzxuLMYwDlL5crsFx+I88ytxbgAdkBB+DmJLjrEEcXeH4itYDZjkK4-ok6gXnHUFkcAg6GQBHoMBU5HUIC4+8Px6Ysaz8wA9C-wboULAjOgtzvxMWfosHQ2B4IQALtlIMgAIwAEw3FwvD8N0rqXHUeIwK6CHUpQ1B0K6ABWPD0HUWGgKoXz1uEYD0B6AKzlWzg8Cwdw7FwcJHEYFRQTWcowB0ijwO82HkBxiJcUhLrNn0cQJKIwnsc4nEVLh1bSe0wxwApIA5mwQA)

Comment: You could keep `(data: T) => unknown`. `Validator<any>` is required because function arguments are contravariant, but that's a great answer.

Comment: Ah yes, that's why `any` was needed. `unknown` is quite longer to type than `any`, though. Doubly longer!

Comment: haha, sure, I like to reduce the use of `any` to better document where it's truly needed (like mutable variables and so on). It makes maintenance easier, but you do you

Comment: Well... it's not really doing anything here but serving as a placeholder. I think it's alright.

Comment: And it still works if one uses `never` instead of `[TypeError, "Validator type does not match with value provider."]`